# Are there ANY text strings that will generate the same SHA-512 Hash output?

Tags: encryption, hash, sha-512

Are there ANY text strings that will generate the same SHA-512 Hash output? Please provide an example, and how you came to that conclusion.

I've tried thousands of variations, including ".." vs. "." and "..." vs "..,". I believe it IS possible, I just don't know HOW I can find those 2 magic text strings.

Comment: Yes, but it's supposed to be hard to find an example. $\;$

Comment: You could do it, provided you checked all the possibilities. Count them, and you'll know.

Comment: Typically similar strings will produce vastly different SHA hashes but it would be very interesting if there was a case where two similar strings produced the same hash

Comment: Comments and answers use the phrase "hard to find". More accurate might be "possible in theory, but no-one has yet done it despite many attempts".

Comment: Already answered at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12301/351 and http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8765/351; see also http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/301/351 and http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8092/351.  In the future please make more of an effort to search for related questions here before posting a new one.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. It must be said that those questions would be hard to link to each other if you're not a cryptographer. Then again, maybe we don't want this question for every hash algorithm... We could rework this question somewhat to mean every possible SHA-2 hash maybe. That would at least take care of the most common 4 (+ 2).

Comment: @Neil Slater: In cryptography, the term 'hard' means that there is no known practical way to compute a solution in a reasonable time (e.g., it would take billions of years).

Comment: @Chris: I didn't think OP would be familiar with that meaning, it is jargon.

Answer (score 11):

This is trivially true via the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). SHA-2/512 has $2^{512}$ possible outputs, but $2^{2^{128}} - 1$ possible inputs. Trying $2^{512}+1$ unique inputs is sufficient to produce at least one collision.

That said, SHA-2/512 is designed to be [collision resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance), which implies that it *should* be hard to find two inputs that hash to the same value. Finding a way to quickly create such a collision would be considered a catastrophic break in the algorithm.

Today it is considered unfeasible to even find *one* SHA-512 collision - none have been found so far. There have been efforts to find a collision for SHA-1 though (notably the IAIK "SHA-1-Collison Search Graz Project"); it is thought that the SHA-1 algorithm is sufficiently broken to find one. These attacks don't translate to SHA-512 because of the increased complexity of the algorithm and the higher output size of the hash.

Comment: Added a paragraph about *slowly* finding a hash collision instead of "quickly*

Comment: See [this article](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/09/the_doghouse_cr.html) about why finding such a collision is really, really unlikely. To just count from 0 to 2^512 would take much more energy then the whole universe is likely to contain.

Comment: There isn't an infinite number of possible inputs. SHA-512 uses a 128 bit length field, which means it is undefined for inputs which are $2^{128}$ bits or longer. So the total number of possible inputs is $2^{2^{128}}-1$.

Comment: Good point. I've edited the answer to reflect that.